# xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null ); application works from flat json file but not from a http request

Tags: jquery, json, express

I have a getjson command that works fine from a file data.json

```
$.getJSON('data.json')
```

However when I try to connect to an express service 
`$.getJSON('http://x.x.x.x:3000/list/json')` it fails with no error message

which is presented by express hosted on the same machine
the json is perfectly formed the same as the  file in the browser e.g. 
`http://x.x.x.x:3000/list/json`  is the same as data.json

from the developer tools I get the error message

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

Any ideas?

`x.x.x.x = local host`

in Internet Explorer  json required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) I've  enable this on node.js express following

http://bannockburn.io/2013/09/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-with-a-node-js-express-js-and-sencha-touch-app/

But still getting

XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

Comment: what is the exact error message? Please provide some more overall context/code.

Comment: Does the Express is sending content type as JSON? Try adding on the server server.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); before sending